# List all processes without controlling terminal (only)?

Tags: posix, ps, portability, controlling-terminal

Is there a portable way to do this?

On Linux, I can use `ps a -N`
but this option isn't available on other (POSIX) systems.

Of course I can use `grep '^?'` with, say, `-o tty,...` but is there something more reliable?

Answer (score 0):

Standard `ps` allows you to get information about all processes using its `-A` option, and to get specific fields using `-o`, for example the `TTY` field.

The issue is that the TTY field's string is formatted differently between systems. On Linux, a process without controlling TTY will have its TTY reported as `?`, while FreeBSD uses `-`, and both macOS and OpenBSD use `??`.

If you want to use the system's `ps` to perform this task, you could start by figuring out what string to look for to identify a process without a terminal.

You could use `ps -p 1 -o tty=` for this, assuming PID 1 is an existing process without a controlling terminal.  This should output `?` on Linux, `??` on macOS and OpenBSD, and `-` on FreeBSD. You would then use this string to filter the output from `ps -A -o tty,pid`.

In the command below, I'm also trimming off any blanks from the output of that `ps` command:

```bash
ps -A -o tty,pid |
awk -v t="$(ps -p 1 -o tty= | tr -d '[:blank:]')" '$1 == t { print $2 }'
```

This should work in most places, except where PID 1 does not exist and not on Busybox-based systems (since Busybox's implementation of `ps` does not have a `-p` option).